# What is the Asana is that Bhagawan Vishnu is laying down in?

Tags: vishnu, asana

Many images depict *Bhagawan Vishnu* laying on his side with a hand supporting his head. What is this *Asana* called? Also, what does it signify?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean Yoga Nidra?

Comment: @TheDestroyer: No, Yoga Nidra is where you lay on your back not on your sides.

Comment: @TheDestroyer: I have added a sample image

Comment: @SreeCharan: Yes, thats what I said too

Comment: More mysterious down-votes :)